# Sort search results by field values in Solr

Tags: solr

In solr, I have a dynamic fields like first_name, revenue, address etc... Now I have to sort the results based on these dynamic field's values. I know we can only sort by int fields(eg:id). But I need to sort results by text fields also.

Can we achieve this in solr?

I am using solr 4.3 version

Comment: Have you read this ? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502221/solr-sort-query-to-sort-based-on-field-values

Comment: Yes. But I my case a text field sorting by Alphabets. How to do ?

Comment: Hope this helps :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062840/sorting-on-text-field-in-solr